# Refresh the page and then go to a specific div that is in another hidden div without using cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a grid of tabs and each tab has items that are hidden by default:

```
#tab1, #tab2, #tab3 etc.
```

Each tab has:

```
#item1, #item2, #item3 etc.
```

The ids are coming from a cms and cannot be changed so you have duplicate ids: **#item1 can refer to the div in both #tab1 and #tab2**.

The user clicks on #tab2 and shows the #tab2. The url changes to example.com/page#tab2, then he clicks on an item (#item5) inside that tab and the entire item shows. The url becomes `example.com/page#item5`.

If the user refreshes that page I would like to show the item5 in tab2.

Is it possible to do it without cookies? Given that the ids cannot be changed or insert some data-attributes I'm not sure how I can show the desired item on page reload.

Comment: While it may well be possible to use cookies/localstorage/whatever data store as a workaround, you issue is solely caused by the badly designed URL fragments and duplicate `id` attributes. I would suggest that your time would be better spent addressing those issues.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan about the duplicate ids I cannot do anything because the html cannot be changed. But what do you mean about `badly designed URL fragments` ? How can the url be improved?

Comment: Place both the parent tab and item in the fragment, eg. `#tab2-item5`

Comment: _“The ids are coming from a cms and cannot be changed so you have duplicate ids”_ - you mean actual IDs in the HTML? Then the CMS sucks, and this _must_ be changed - IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: @CBroe I know. To be fair it isn't actually the cms. The html of a component cannot be changed because it is global (across thousands of our sites). If you make a change you'll deploy it everywhere. Anyway all of this comes from a poor architectural decision. I think it was thought that improvements would be easier to deploy everywhere but now you have the issue that no-one wants to test so many sites or has permission to do it => lots of hacks in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get url hash, when page loaded like this: `var currentTabId = location.hash`.

After that you can scroll page to `div` element whose `id` equals `currentTabId`.

Comment: How would I know which is currentTabId?

Comment: For example you can add both ids to `location.hash` and parse it when page loaded

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to change the URL schema to:

domain.ext/page#tabs2/#item5

This will be easily solvable with JS after you parse the URL.